# A question about add_action()

Tags: plugin-development, actions, oop

I was following this ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API ) tut on codex. The part where a class is created and is called in add_action. No argument was passed to `emailer::send` ? Why? It was required in the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `emailer::send` is the function callback for a `publish_post` action hook. This action hook accepts only one parameter which is the post ID and it is passed by Wordpress.

When you define an action hook, you set what parameters are passed to the callback functions. For example:

```
$arg_1 = "The aregument value";
do_action( 'my_custom_action', $arg_1 );
```

Every time you hook into `my_custom_action`, the `$arg_1` value is passed to the function callback automatically.

```
add_action( 'my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback' );
function my_custom_action_callback( $arg_1 ) {
    //Do whatever
}
```

In the example you are talking about, the [`publish_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) action hook is is used. This action hook accept one argument, the post ID, and this argumente is passed to `emailer:send` automatically by Wordpress.

Comment: So, what you are actually trying to say is that this `$post_ID` is predefined by wordpress. Right?

Comment: @Faiz When you do an `add_action(...)` all your doing is registering an 'observer' (or callback function) which is called when the appropriate action is performed. That callback will be passed the first argument associated with that action. In the example above, the post ID.